# Workflows as GenServers

Tags: architecture, elixir, modeling

So I have occasionally dabbled with Elixir, but the thing that I struggled with in the past is always how to model an application with processes. With this in mind I want to sanity check something I am about to do to see if it makes sense.

So I am building a simple workflow application, each stage will have rules about how it flows to the next stage(s), state it may collect and events that are fired as a result of the state change. Stages are not linear and are essentially a graph as in any flow chart diagram.

My first thought looking at a flow diagram is that it looks very much like a collection of processes.

My though was to model each stage in the flow as its own GenServer as they are addressable, can hold state and can be used to execute events.

If this is a sensible approach (let me know if it isn't) then I have a few questions:

- As this is a graph each stage can have multiple connected next and previous stages. I would want these stages to be supervised, now I am really going to show my lack of understanding here but am I right in thinking that a supervisor only monitors processes linked to it, and not there child processes? If this is the case I kind of want each stage to act as a GenServer and a supervisor, is this possible/sensible?
- Is there a way to get all the child processes of a process?
- Is this sensible?

Chris

Comment: _Sidenote:_ “as a GenServer and a supervisor”—[`Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html) _is_ a `GenServer` in a nutshell.

Comment: Yeah, I knew this I was more asking if if was appropriate to use them as things other than doe supervision. I didn't make this clear, so thanks for the clarification anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at how [Plug](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug), the behaviour that Phoenix is built on, works. Basically, each function (plug) that is defined accepts and returns a struct, `conn`, and a piped chain of plugs gradually builds it up/transform it/etc.

If I'm understanding you correctly, this pattern would work - you build a struct/map initially, and you simply pass that through a set of functions that gradually transform it. You should be able to branch as well, it doesn't need to be linear. That way the state remains in one place (all you need to do is keep hold of that struct, which you can do with a single genserver).

Although it's tempting to do it, I would seriously avoid modelling each step as a genserver: this is abusing them to try to emulate objects. Using plain functions that just rebuild the state will be much simpler, easier to debug, and more idiomatic ([this article](http://www.theerlangelist.com/article/spawn_or_not) explains when to use processes and when to not use processes, and why, in a bit more detail).

Comment: Yeah I have come to this conclusion, not so much about Plug but about having a GenServer per stage. I think I will have one per whole flow instance.

Answer (score 1):

GenServers are defintely one way you can accomplish something like this, but you'll have to solve a few implementations issues when going this way.

So it's a good thing that Elixir already provides a higher-level implmentation for exactly this, called [**GenStage**](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html). You can create pipelines with many stages, where each stage can act as a consumer, producer or both.

You can also spawn further child-processes in each stage or have these stages do the work themselves and use a [**ConsumerSupervisor**](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/ConsumerSupervisor.html) to supervise them.

[image]

You can also have multiple stages run in parallel feeding data to other stages, where the bulk of the implementation is handled by it automatically.

[image]

---

**Here are some resources:**

- [Official Github](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage)
- [HexDocs Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html)
- [Video: Jose's Keynote on GenStage and Flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srtMWzyqdp8&feature=youtu.be&t=244)
- [Blog Post: Understanding GenStage in Elixir](https://sheharyar.me/blog/understanding-genstage-elixir/)
- [Examples](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/tree/master/examples)

Comment: Hey thanks and yeah I know about GenStage, but I see the main use case for this in processing loads of data through a flow. Im talking more about long lived business workflows where small amounts of state move through it i.e. someone completes a form, this moves to a stage where several people need approves it and sends them emails...etc. I see GenStage is more around handling back pressure, and flows of lots of data. It it appropriate from something like this?

Comment: As mentioned this is exactly not what I am looking to do

Answer (score 1):

I think the process tree does not need to have the same topology of the graph.

What I would do is using only one Supervisor for each graph, all the processes in this graph will be supervisored by it.

Use `Supervisor.which_children/1` to get all the child processes of a Supervisor.

And I believe [using a Supervisor as a GenServer is a bad practice](https://elixirforum.com/t/are-supervisor-processes-genserver-processes/1838).